# Why is my .xslm file corrupted during download?

Tags: java, jquery, excel, apache-poi

So here is the situation:

I have a .xslm file (a macro enabled excel worksheet) on server. There are no issues in opening this file on server (using ms-excel 2013).
I then edit the file using Apache POI 3.13. Save a copy of this file on server and give the other to the user for download.
(This is done just to check if we have any write issues while editing. The original purpose was just to give it as download)
The copy of this file saved on server is opened without any issues. But the one sent as download throws [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhenX.png) error while opening it from excel 2013.

I am using `Jquery.fileDownload()` on the client side to make the ajax call to the server where I have my Spring Controller serving the file.

Here is my code to write the file:

```
    Workbook workbook = null;
    ServletOutputStream out = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;

    try {

        OPCPackage inputFilePackage = OPCPackage.open(<original file saved on server>);
        workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputFilePackage);

        //Do Some stuff to edit workbook here

        fos = new FileOutputStream("temp.xlsm");
        workbook.write(fos);
        fos.close();

        inputStream = new FileInputStream("temp.xlsm"); // The file that is created just now

        servletResponse.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12");
        servletResponse.setHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=NewFile.xlsm");
        servletResponse.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "fileDownload=true; path=/");
        out = servletResponse.getOutputStream();
        // workbook.write(out); // Was previously using this method to directly write to ServletOutputStream 

        int i;
        while ((i = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
            out.write(i);
        }
        out.flush();
        // new File("temp.xlsm").delete();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    finally {
        if (out != null) {
            try {
                out.close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                LOGGER.error(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
        if (inputStream != null) {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                LOGGER.error(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    return "success";
```

Also I can clearly see the difference between the size of both the files.
The file which is opening without issues is (436,129 bytes) while the file throwing the error is (436,136 bytes). I am not sure from where these extra bytes are coming.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: new FileInputStream("temp.xlsm") you wrote to doc.getLocalFilePath() + "temp.xlsm" typo?

Comment: As the received file is longer then there is no data loss, and it sounds like the results are predictable - it's a hard fault - so chances are you aren't saving it to file in binary mode.

Comment: @PetterFriberg. Yes that was a typo.. Edited.

Comment: @barny What can I do to correct it?

Comment: It's your code, debug it. Break the problem down. The received data on disk is is getting longer - where is that happening? Maybe if you print the length of the received data before writing to file that will tell you something if it is same as/different from the source file size and the received file size on disk. And if you print the length of data sent you can check to see if that is what you expect.

Comment: Does workbook.write(out); work?

Comment: @PetterFriberg.. Yes it did work.. But same issue was there in that case too

Comment: so it did not : ).... you are sure that you don't pass anything else on the getOutputStream() in some other place.... seems that someone else is adding the bytes...

Comment: Yes.. absolutely sure.. The scope of outputStream is limited to this function only. and I do not see anything else using that..

Comment: Couldn't find anything that worked. One more finding was there. There were only 7 bytes that were added to the size of file.

Comment: As a work-around I have zipped the file on server and then sent it to download. I doesn't corrupt the zip.